# What evidence has the ICC relied on in ordering the arrest of the President of Russia?

Tags: russian-federation, ukraine, vladimir-putin, donbass, international-criminal-court

A few days ago, International Criminal Court prosecutor Karim Khan [said](https://www.icc-cpi.int/news/statement-prosecutor-karim-khan-kc-issuance-arrest-warrants-against-president-vladimir-putin):

> Today, the Pre-Trial Chamber has issued **arrest warrants** in relation to the following two individuals:
>
> - Mr Vladimir Putin, **President of the Russian Federation**; and
> - Ms Maria Lvova-Belova, Commissioner for Children’s Rights in the Office of the  President of the Russian Federation.
>
> On the basis of evidence collected and analysed by my Office pursuant to its independent investigations, the Pre-Trial Chamber has confirmed that there are reasonable grounds to believe that President Putin and Ms Lvova-Belova bear criminal responsibility for the unlawful deportation and transfer of Ukrainian children from occupied areas of Ukraine to the Russian Federation, contrary to article 8(2)(a)(vii) and article 8(2)(b)(viii) of the Rome Statute.
>
> Incidents identified by my Office include the deportation of at least hundreds of children taken from orphanages and children’s care homes. Many of these children, we allege, have since been given for adoption in the Russian Federation. The law was changed in the Russian Federation, through Presidential decrees issued by President Putin, to expedite the conferral of Russian citizenship, making it easier for them to be adopted by Russian families.

I was a bit surprised by the particular charge, as I've followed acts such as the bombardment of (dual-use) civil infrastructure (energy, railways), and have heard allegations of intentional targeting of civilians in some cases, but this is the first I've heard of this movement-of-children thing.

What evidence has the court based its decision to issue arrest warrants on?

In particular, evacuating children from war-zones is something which I would assume happens, so what is the indication that children were moved where it is not allowed to move them, and with the intention of not returning them? Does it have something to do with the question of the recognition of the LPR and DPR as independent states and their later accession to the Russian Federation, after which orphans may perhaps have been treated as "any Russian orphan", without care to let them stay within the territories of the LPR/DPR?

Comment: Is [this answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/78837/42582) sufficient?

Comment: @TadeuszKopec: No, because it makes an argument rather than listing evidence.

Comment: @einpoklum Evidence [is here](https://hub.conflictobservatory.org/portal/apps/sites/#/home/pages/children-camps-1)

Comment: @TadeuszKopec: So, is this the evidence the ICC is relying on? If it is, make it an answer. Although others have said there isn't transparency w.r.t. the evidence the ICC considers before issuing warrants, so maybe we just don't know.

Comment: @TadeuszKopec I think the OP is rather asking about the *legal evidence* that the Prosecutor is going to present in the court. And there are [reasons to believe](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/78841/2984) it can be only disclosed in the court, not earlier.

Comment: "this is the first I've heard of this movement-of-children" It was in the news several times though. Not saying that everyone has to have heard of it, but one could have. Obviously the treatment of Civilians during a war is an extremely sensitive matter. The absolute minimum should be the Geneva convention in this regard.

Comment: @einpoklum Obie is [waxing lyrical](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1uYWYWPc9HU).

Comment: @Trilarion: 1. I explained why I was surprised, I didn't say it has not been reported. 2. We probably don't live in the same country, so it's unlikely we get the same news.

Comment: @einpoklum You might be surprised and I try to also get international news if possible. I don't want to put too much emphasis on that comment. Just wanted to mention that the topic isn't new.

Comment: Changing citizenship would appear to support the allegation of "intention of not returning them".  And that seems itself to cross the line into a prohibited movement, there's no this AND ALSO that required.

Comment: While I also think that this order by Putin is motivated by a goal of turning Ukrainian-born children into loyal Russians, and hence fits the allegation, I am somewhat uncomfortable because I don't know what kind of national identity those children would have (if any), if left to decide for themselves? Who knows, some might think of themselves as Russians? During the USSR reign many ethnic Russians had moved to other to other former Soviet Republics. Of course, they could have relocated when USSR dissolved, but many elected not to.

Comment: (cont'd) Having said that, I'm even more uncomfortable with the idea of the Russian Federation using such people (who chose to live in another country) as casus belli, which is basically one of their excuses for starting this war. The real war crimes happened in places like Bucha. It's just that pointing Putin as the culprit there is a stretch. To this extent, the decision to concentrate on the deportation of children feels a bit ... secondary?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : "Who knows, some might think of themselves as Russians? " <- 1. It could be a dual identity psychologically as well... 2. We actually do have some idea, at least for the Donbass areas, as they have seceded from Ukraine and had been at war with it for almost a decade before the invasion; and for Crimea if that's also part of the allegation. That's not certain knowledge, but it is at least a gray area.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> What evidence has the court based its decision to issue arrest warrants on?

It is not disclosed.
The Rome Statute 58(3) does not require so.
From the Rome Statute 58(1)(b)(ii) it follows that the premature disclosure could be deemed undesired/prohibited.

---

The Rome Statute 58(3) is pretty much specific:

> **Article 58**
> **Issuance by the Pre-Trial Chamber of a warrant of arrest or a summons to appear**
> 3. The warrant of arrest shall contain:
> (a) The name of the person and any other relevant identifying information;
> (b) A specific reference to the crimes within the jurisdiction of the Court for which the person's arrest is sought; and
> (c) A concise statement of the facts which are alleged to constitute those crimes.

…and nothing beyond that.

This is precisely the format of Karim Khan's statement quoted within the original question: paragraphs 1,2,3 correspond to sections (a),(b),(c).

Additionally,

> **Article 58**
> **Issuance by the Pre-Trial Chamber of a warrant of arrest or a summons to appear**
>
> 1. […]  the Pre-Trial Chamber shall, on the application of the
>    Prosecutor, issue a warrant of arrest of a person if […]
>    (b) The arrest of the person appears necessary:
>    (ii) To ensure that the person does not obstruct or endanger the investigation or the court proceedings;

I am not a lawyer, but from the common sense, I may assume that *the premature disclosure of evidence would aid the suspect to obstruct the investigation* and thus jeopardize 58(1)(b)(ii).
Therefore, it may be deemed unnecessary, not recommended, harmful, or even prohibited.

Source: [Rome Statute of the International Criminal Court (PDF)](https://www.icc-cpi.int/sites/default/files/RS-Eng.pdf)

---

If you are rather interested of hints about what *could* be the evidence:

- [Deportations with a goal of forced change of victims' identity](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/78837/2984)

Comment: Well, that's... kind of terrible, IMHO. It's bad enough that state bodies can arrest me without establishing cause :-(

Comment: ... but just to be clear, I upvoted and accepted the answer, I just don't like that this is how the ICC works. And it's certainly doesn't inspire public confidence in the process.

Comment: @einpoklum I think many of us want justice public. On the other hand, I cannot imagine a court that would publish something like: *"Here are photos of **[Russian torture chambers for children](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_torture_chambers_in_Ukraine#Torture_chambers_for_children)** which we find authentic. Here is evidence proving that Army General X received order from Supreme Commander Putin to build those chambers"*. I could imagine such materials arise during the hearings in the court, but as evidence to support the arrest warrant — no.

Comment: @einpoklum - Is it standard in your country for all the evidence behind arrest warrants to be made public? I would not assume that lack of publicly divulged information about the evidence for the warrant means that cause has not been established to the satisfaction of the issuing court. There are reasons for this, too: for instance, does one want a suspect who has not been arrested yet to know exactly what your warrant is based on, so that they know what to destroy before they are arrested?

Comment: @Obie2.0: If one of your neighbors had the power to arrest you, would you be ok with that happening based on evidence they did not have to disclose to anybody? Because they are worried you might tamper with their investigation?

Comment: @einpoklum similarities with civil law are quite often imperfect. However, if you insist: (1) it is not a neighbor but rather a police officer; (2) a policeman who knocks on your door for your arrest says "*Rodion Raskolnikov*, you are detained for murder of *Alyona Ivanovna*." He never says, "here's the axe covered with blood, and *Student Pestriakov* has already testified against you". (3) Publicly demanding the evidence upon your detention (`kakije vashi dokazatelstva`) [does not even help](https://youtu.be/SjolD8_HfMs) in movies. :-) Does it make sense?

Comment: @einpoklum I think you need to check how police actually work: all that is usually required is "reasonable suspicion" at the time. It's often the start of gathering more evidence.

Comment: @pjc50: I know that's how police work. That is a prerogative of the sovereign, which is rather oppressive to subjects. In an international setting, the ICC is not a court of the "world government", it is a court arranged among peer-states. You could say that the Rome Statute extends sovereign privileges to the ICC w.r.t. any individual in the signatory states, but that's a problem for the interests of those states - they can be targeted, harassed or assaulted by having key officials be arrested. I doubt ICC members except things to work like that.

Comment: @BeBraveBeLikeUkraine: A police officer is an agent of the sovereign. But in the ICC, there is no international sovereign.

Comment: @einpoklum , absolutely. (1) That's exactly why I mentioned that making analogies with civil law is flawed logic. The ICC is in no way a [neighbor](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/78835/78841#comment338044_78841) of Russia. (2) And it was established specifically for cases like this. (3) Also, from various aspects of its sovereignty in no way it follows that the [evidence](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/78835/78841#comment338044_78841) should be presented in front. Q.E.D.

Comment: @einpoklum read the whole article 58.  Cause must be established to the satisfaction of pre-trial chamber through an application that includes a summary of the evidence.  You will really be much better informed by reading the Rome Statute than by seeking answers from the users of this site, or at least by reading it before you seek those answers.  The ICC is also constituted in a way that protects the interests of member states without requiring public disclosure of evidence before arrest.

Comment: @phoog: I guess I should read the thing... especially since I doubt the interests of member states are protected if arrests of their political leadership are possible without disclosure of evidence.

Comment: @einpoklum: It's worth noting that while they will say *why* they're charging you with a crime, if the police are using a search warrant, knock or no-knock, they do so not necessarily to charge the person with a crime, but to consider it a possibility the person *has* evidence of a crime done by *someone* - not necessarily the person being searched.  With no-knock warrants issued when they have a reason to suspect the person may destroy the evidence being searched for. Similarly, as I understand, the police*can*arrest a suspect before an investigation is complete on the evidence and testimony.

Answer (score 9):

Reports first emerged last spring that Ukrainian children in occupied territory were being taken to Russia, and some adopted by Russian families. This includes children taken from Ukrainian state institutions in the occupied areas, children whose parents had sent them to Russian-run “summer camps” from which they never returned, children whose parents were arrested by the Russian occupying authorities, and children who were orphaned by the fighting. **Russia has admitted** to holding at least 1,400 Ukrainian children it describes as orphans ([source](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2023/mar/17/vladimir-putin-war-crimes-icc-arrest-warrant-ukraine-children), The Guardian).

Many of these Ukrainian children have living relatives, who are desperately searching for them.

Russia has not publicly issued a list of Ukrainian children evacuated and detained. However V. Putin issued a decree that made it quick and easy to adopt Ukrainian children, this is obviously not a secret. Also, Russian officials **do not deny** Ukrainian children are now in Russia ([source](https://www.npr.org/2023/02/14/1156500561/russia-ukraine-children-deportation-possible-war-crime-report), NPR). ICC concluded that "there are reasonable grounds" to suspect this is actually happening ([source](https://www.icc-cpi.int/news/situation-ukraine-icc-judges-issue-arrest-warrants-against-vladimir-vladimirovich-putin-and), the arrest warrant itself):

> (...) responsible for the war crime of unlawful deportation of population (children) and that of unlawful transfer of population (children) from occupied areas of Ukraine to the Russian Federation (under articles 8(2)(a)(vii) and 8(2)(b)(viii) of the Rome Statute). The crimes were allegedly committed in Ukrainian occupied territory at least from 24 February 2022. There are reasonable grounds to believe that.

The United Nation’s prevention of genocide convention prohibits “forcibly transferring children of the group to another group”

Comment: 1. That doesn't say what the evidence for the claims is, and specifically not what the ICC based the warrant on. 2. AFAIK, and I may be wrong, the Guardian has not had reporters stationed in the Donbass (or Zaporizhya, or Russia etc.), looking into the issue of child deportations. In another news story they link to a report by the USA. Do you believe that it's this report on which the ICC based its warrant?

Comment: Russia has itself admitted to holding at least 1,400 Ukrainian children. Hence ICC had reasons to assume this maybe have happened.

Comment: 1. Citation needed... 2. There are many people (including children) who are both Russian and Ukranian - ethnicity vs citizenship, or with both states recognizing them as their citizens.

Comment: There are two references.

Comment: @einpoklum the crime alleged in the arrest warrant does not depend on the children's citizenship or ethnicity but on their place of residence.

Answer (score 5):

Is the *indictment* public? (As opposed to the press release.) I couldn't find the former. That was not an uncommon strategy for ICTY as well (before apprehending the suspects), as I vaguely recall. Evidence can be destroyed, witnesses suppressed etc. One [article](https://jfjustice.net/sealed-indictments-hurt-defence-teams-car-suspect-tells-icc/) notes that ICC itself has done this in the past, e.g. regarding some CAR suspects:

> The sealed indictments were invented at the International Criminal Tribunal for the Former Yugoslavia, the first contemporaneous international criminal court and thus the predecessor of the ICC, by Louise Arbour, who was chief prosecutor of the ICTY from 1996 till 1999. The ICTY was then in a situation similar to the ICC now: there were many outstanding arrest warrants, partly against high-level suspects, but there had not been arrests for quite some time. [...] So Arbour resorted to the sealed indictments to facilitate and encourage arrests. UN troops that were present in various parts of the former Yugoslavia, could use the element of surprise when executing the arrest warrants. This led to a new series of arrests soon.

and [also](https://jfjustice.net/icc-issues-arrest-warrants-for-putin-and-lvova-belova-in-ukraine-conflict/) in this case:

> While the ICC has authorized the Registry to publicly disclose the existence of the arrest warrants, the actual text of the warrants remains confidential.

Anyhow, we have somewhat more information in this case than from totally sealed indictments, at least in the form of the press release:

> Khan stated that 100s of the children taken from orphanages and children’s care homes in Ukraine have since been given for adoption in the Russian Federation. **He added that the law was changed in the Russian Federation through Presidential decrees issued by President Putin to expedite the conferral of Russian citizenship, making it easier for them to be adopted by Russian families. The prosecutor also alleged that these acts demonstrate an intention to remove these children from their own country permanently.**

I *suspect*, based on press coverage of the affair, that an indictment may in part rely on Putin's [prior](https://blogs.lse.ac.uk/lseih/2020/07/01/there-is-no-ukraine-fact-checking-the-kremlins-version-of-ukrainian-history/) declarations that Ukraine is a fake/country nation in order to establish his intent in regard to those children.

You ask/say:

> In particular, evacuating children from war-zones is something which I would assume happens, so what is the indication that children were moved where it is not allowed to move them, and with the intention of not returning them?

The NYT for example [says](https://www.nytimes.com/2022/10/22/world/europe/ukraine-children-russia-adoptions.html):

> Mr. Putin instituted a streamlined process in May allowing the swift nationalization of Ukrainian children. The first group became Russian citizens in July, officials announced.
>
> “I did not recognize those kids with whom we traveled in April on the train to their new life,” Ksenia Mishonova, the children’s rights commissioner for the Moscow region, said in a statement. “Now they are our little fellow citizens!”

So it's probably more than simply/temporarily taking the children to Russia that's going to be used as evidence, [possibly](https://theconversation.com/are-russian-transfers-of-ukrainian-children-to-re-education-and-adoption-facilities-a-form-of-genocide-200995) in an attempt to establish some kind of similarity with [more odious precedents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kidnapping_of_children_by_Nazi_Germany). But I'm just guessing, since the ICC has released very little details about their indictment, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Aren't complaints submitted to the ICC, and the evidence that backs them, supposed to be public?

Comment: @einpoklum: isn't that a diffrent Q? The answer seems to be 'no', it isn't. Whether it *should* be [before an arrest] seems be a matter of opinion. https://www.jstor.org/stable/44218540

Comment: And the ICC [not just ICTY] also used this practice before (and was thrashed for it by some https://jfjustice.net/sealed-indictments-hurt-defence-teams-car-suspect-tells-icc/) In fact, another article of the same source say/confirms in the Putin case
"While the ICC has authorized the Registry to publicly disclose the existence of the arrest warrants, the actual text of the warrants remains confidential." https://jfjustice.net/icc-issues-arrest-warrants-for-putin-and-lvova-belova-in-ukraine-conflict/

Comment: Wow, I would not have thought that to be the case. I mean, presuming to arrest a head-of-state is a big deal, it honestly seems rather preposterous that the ICC would not need a very solid and publicly available basis in order to expect ICC members to execute such warrants. But ok.

Comment: @einpoklum I don’t think anyone really cares about the crime mentioned in the press release. Putin’s actual crime is starting a war of aggression, the “kidnapping” accusation is merely an excuse to bring him to court. Kind of like Al Capone and taxes.

Comment: @JonathanReez Note though that he can only be tried for the crime he is being accused of. So he can't really be tried for war of aggression if that isn't what he is accused of.

Comment: @sfxedit He's accused of that crime, however, another question asks and answers why the war of aggression is not listed in the ICC warrant. https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/78829/why-is-the-icc-focusing-on-the-transfer-of-war-orphans-to-russia-rather-than-rus

Comment: @JonathanReez: But in the Al Capone case, it was the court of the sovereign, and here it is a court of peers at best, and a court of belligerents in some cases.

Comment: @DavidS The answer in the cited question are wrong as "war of aggression" does indeed come under ICC mandate.

Comment: @einpoklum sorry but Putin is undeniably an authoritarian leader who started the biggest European war since WWII. He deserves to go behind bars, though I agree that ICC's particular accusation is flimsy at best.

Comment: @JonathanReez: I don't see how your comment relates to mine.

Comment: @sfxedit "he can only be tried for the crime he is being accused of": that is incorrect.  After a defendant is arrested, additional charges can be brought before the trial begins.  The most obvious scenario in which this could happen is the discovery of new evidence after arrest.

Comment: @sfedit: What phoog said, but also; there's also degrees of a crime - whether they can charge for first, second, or third degree, depending on what the evidence in an investigation indicates is more probable to lead to a conviction beyond a reasonable doubt. Even before counting serial cases.

Comment: @phoog Since this is still in the pre-trial stages that is correct. But right *now*, Putin isn't accused of "war of aggression" and that's because it would bring focus on Ukraine's own political misadventures too - from the time they signed the Minsk accord to the actions they took against Russian speaking Ukranians. That would reveal that the case of "war of aggression" isn't really as strong against Russia as the western propaganda paints it.

Comment: @sfxedit the amendment to the Rome Statute that governs the crime of aggression doesn't appear to allow the court to assume jurisdiction over that crime by the invitation of a state that isn't a party to the statute, so it's not likely that it would ever accept charges of aggression against Putin. ("In respect of a State that is not a party to this Statute, the Court shall not exercise its jurisdiction over the crime of aggression when committed by that State’s nationals or on its 
territory.") Genocide is a different matter.

Comment: Russia no longer recognizes Ukraine's sovereignity over these four regions and has formally included these, so obviously it's going to remove *everybody there* from Ukraine and to Russia permanently, usually without the physical change of place of residence. The whole ICC case is thus bogus.

Comment: @alamar: sure, but some of those events took place before the formal annexation, IIRC. So even if the ICC somehow were to recognize those annexations as legal (which you can bet it won't), the matter would still not be moot, from ICC's perspective. Russia, of course, doesn't recognize ICC's authority, as they're not part to the treaty. From Russia's leaders perspective, being prosecuted by the ICC with Ukraine's nod, or by Ukrainian prosecutors directly is nearly the same thing.

Comment: ICC is not a body that has power to treat annexations as legal or not. Else you get farce where "family grocery shopping is normally okay, but if you live in Donetsk it is treated as a war crime".

Comment: @alamar: obviously it does. Otherwise any country that's a member could declare to annex a neighbor, invade, and the "crime of aggression" would be nullified beforehand. It's like you declaring your neighbor part of your state and imposing the death penalty on them, i.e. killing them, and the declaring that no court has authority because you are a sovereign over your neighbor. Courts in general decide  for themselves Kompetenz-Kompetenz. That others may no always recognize them that power is another matter.

Comment: @alamar: BTW, the ICC has already decided something like that, or least its prosecutor has, when it decided to recognize Palestine, i.e. the OPT, as under the court's jurisdiction, despite the Israeli, US, and UK opposition. That hasn't translated into any cases in those territories yet, for reasons of funding, access, and surely some other kinds of pressures too. There's a recent Q here about that, BTW.

Comment: @alamar: It was almost funny how Israel when from https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2021/4/8/israel-to-tell-icc-it-does-not-recognise-courts-authority to https://www.reuters.com/world/middle-east/icc-prosecutor-visit-israel-request-oct-7-hamas-attack-victims-2023-11-30/ ; https://www.icc-cpi.int/news/icc-prosecutor-karim-khan-kc-concludes-first-visit-israel-and-state-palestine-icc-prosecutor after Oct 7.

Comment: @Fizz Genocide within your own borders is not legally much different from genocide via invasion. The only case that starts falling apart is the child trafficking claims. Makes me wonder is that they've deliberately chose an accusation that they may make fall apart at any moment, depending on how the negotiation is going.